# Push value of input to array if innerText empty in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons and inputs. I am trying to push innerText to array. Since there are different types of tags I need to specify 'if' to pick either the value for inputs or innerText of buttons.

This is what I have so far:

```
if ($("#dragulaContainer2").children().length > 0) {
  var arraySelected = [];
  var children = $('#dragulaContainer2').children();

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    arraySelected.push(children[i].innerText);
  }
  console.log(arraySelected);
}
```

My non-coding logic behind it would be:

If childrens inner Text equals "" than take value instead.

But how to build the code? And add it to `innerText` line as if statement?

Added this but it is not working....

```
if ($("#dragulaContainer2").children().length > 0) {
  var arraySelected = [];
  var children = $('#dragulaContainer2').children();

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

    arraySelected.push(children[i].(if (innerText === "") {
      val
    } else {
      innerText
  });
}
console.log(arraySelected);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you'd do exactly as you described in your question. Have you done that yet?

Comment: Dont have any idea how to write it... Does it go before `for` loop? Does it go inside?

Comment: There should be a `children[i].tagName` you can reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, *if no **text**, push the **value** instead*

```js
var arraySelected = $("#dragulaContainer2").find(":input").map(function() {
  return this.textContent || this.value;
}).get();

console.log( arraySelected );
```

```html
<div id="dragulaContainer2">
  <input value="0">
  <input value="test 1">
  <span>test 2</span>
  <textarea>test 3</textarea>
  <p>test 4</p>
  <button>btn text</button>
  <button value="btn val">use text</button>
  <button value="use value"></button>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or if you use ES6 you can "shorten" to

```
$("#dragulaContainer2").find(":input").map((i,el) => el.textContent || el.value).get();
```

---

Using your `if else` style of coding, it would look like:

```
var $inp = $("#dragulaContainer2").find(":input");
var arraySelected = [];

$inp.each(function(){
    if(this.textContent) {
      arraySelected.push(this.textContent);
    } else {
      arraySelected.push(this.value);
    }
});  

console.log( arraySelected );
```

Comment: Thank you, what would it look like if I wanted to continue with my `if else`?